# Why ConnectionStringOracle.Config Enable by default in sitecore

Tags: configuration

We are using MSSQL db for all the databases(core,master,web) in sitecore, but I can see the ConnectionStringOracle.Config is enabled by default in App_config folder.

```
Sitecore 8.1 Update-2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- 
    Sitecore connection strings.
    All database connections for Sitecore are configured here.
  -->
  <add name="core" connectionString="user id=sccore;password=sccore;Data Source=XE" />
  <add name="master" connectionString="user id=scmaster;password=scmaster;Data Source=XE"/>
  <add name="web" connectionString="user id=scweb;password=scweb;Data Source=XE"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there any purpose for this and if we leave this like this will there be any issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of this file is allow clients who are operating on Oracle to have a default installation file for connecting to these databases.

Unlike Sitecore 'Include' patch files, it does not need to be disabled/enabled because it's use is driven by the reference in the Web.config file (as mentioned by @Dražen Janjiček).

There will be no issue if you leave this file in your App_Config folder, unless you update the Web.config file to point at it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but by default Sitecore targets specifically the general ConnectionStrings.config file. Review your web.config file to be sure.

```
<connectionStrings configSource="App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config" />
```